Redirecting user with middleware with mongoDB (mongoose) and next auth v5
I want to achieve following thing. When registering user I create a mongoDB document. I set isFinalized to false. Now I want to check if user has this set to false or true and if true, before rendering the page I want to redirect him to let's say "/finalize". However I can't combine getting document inside next-auth's session callback and middleware that's getting the session. There's an error stating that mongoose.connect is not a function (it seems that middleware is trying to use mongoose, however I only await auth session there). Is there any other way I can do this? I'd like to have a global solution preferably, without having to writing redirects on each page.
If I do the following:
middleware.ts:
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { auth } from "./auth";

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const session = await auth();
  console.log(session);
}

authOptions:
{
  secret: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session }) => {
      await connectMongoDB();
      if (!session.user.email) {
        return {
          ...session,
          user: {
            ...session.user,
            hasEmail: false,
            isFinalized: false
          }
        };
      }
      const userDB = User.findOne({ email: session.user.email });
      if (!userDB.isFinalized) {
        return {
          ...session,
          user: {
            ...session.user,
            isFinalized: false
          }
        };
      }
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          isFinalized: true
        }
      };
    }
  }
}

I can only have either of those codes, if I put both terminal gives me an error:
connection error [TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).connect is not a function]
[auth][error] JWTSessionError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#jwtsessionerror
[auth][cause]: TypeError: _components_Auth_schema__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.User.findOne is not a function

